# Manipulating time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a lot of data from Trading Economics which have, for some reason, the dates in the following format:

```
1919-09-30T00:00:00
```

Is there a handy way to elaborate this preserving the format of the data in R?
I'm a very beginner with R, I figured out this but everything become string

```
cbind(substr(inflation[,3],1,10),inflation[,4])
```

column 4 contains inflation rate related to a certain date (in column 3)

I am sure there is a smart and quick way to work on the dataframe. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Botvinnik05, have a look at the lubridate package, it has many options of parsing dates.